# Problems with dependency injection using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, mockito

I'm trying to inject a dependency into my class. But for some reason when I am testing it using Mockito, it doesn't work and the object isn't instantiated and remains null.

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="docusign")
public class DocuSignProperties {

private String oAuthBaseUrl;
private String baseUrl;
}
```

In application.properties:

```
#docuSign properties
docusign.oAuthBaseUrl=https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth
docusign.baseUrl=https://demo.docusign.net/restapi
```

The class that is injecting DocuSignProperties:

```
@Component
public class DocuSign {
    @Autowired
    private DocuSignProperties docuSignProperties;

    private ApiClient apiClient;
    private OAuthToken oAuthToken;
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    public DocuSign() {
        this.initialize();
}

    public DocuSign(ProjetoDTO projeto)  {
        this.projeto = projeto;
        this.initialize();
}

    private void initialize() {
    try {
        this.apiClient = new ApiClient(this.docuSignProperties.getBaseUrl()); //here docuSignProperties is null, when should it be instantiated
        this.oAuthToken = getOAuthTokenAcesso();
        this.setApiClientConfigurations();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The class that tests it:

```
public class DocuSignTest {
    private DocuSignProperties docuSignProperties;
    private ProjetoDTO projeto1;
    @Mock
    private DocuSignProperties docuSignProperties;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
       projeto1 = new ProjetoDTO();
       projeto1.setId(1L);
       projeto1.setDsProjeto("projeto1")
    }
  @Test
  public void criarDocumento() throws Exception {
      DocuSign docuSign = new DocuSign(projeto1);
      docuSign.sendDoc();
      assertNotNull(docuSign);
}
```

I would like to know why on initialize method docuSignProperties isn't instantiated.

Comment: in @before you sould use initMocks()

Comment: Not really relevant but can help. Field injection is kind of hidden. If you use constructor injection everything will be crystal clear on how to do things. That works in tests and production code also.

Comment: MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); ? It didn't work ;(

Comment: How should mockito know to inject your mock into `DocuSign` when you don't tell him to do so?

Comment: Your Test class does not compile. You define a variable twice. Do you run your test with MockitoRunner?

Comment: Hi Tom, tks for your time! 
I thought  that when I use @Mock on the attribute, mockitos knows that must to use it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi Jeans, I run it using JUnit

Comment: @oitathi You are partly wrong. That tells Mockito to mock that class, but doesn't tell it to _inject_ it into `DocuSign`. You should think about switching from Field Injection to Compiler Injection, like Michael Michailidis, then the missing "combination" of mock and tested class will become obvious.

Comment: Mock annotations work only with MockitoRunner. So add @RunWith(MockitoRunner.class) to your TestClass

Comment: Hi Apa, yeah, I tried It too and didn't work :(

Comment: @Jeans I added @RunWith(Mockito Runner.class) in my test class importing org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner; but didn't work

Comment: @Tom how I do it? I was searching it on google, but I didn't get the idea

Answer (score 0):

to use annotation Mock you habe to use:

```
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

or add at the beginning of the clas:

```
@RunWith(org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

moreover you have to inject your mock you can use @InjectMocks what I would rather do not recommend but change your constructor or use a setter it depends if that class is mandatory or optional:

```
 @Autowired
 public DocuSign(DocuSignProperties docuSignProperties) {
    this.initialize();
    this.docuSignProperties=docuSignProperties;
 }
```

then in your test when creating your DocuSign you just pass prodSignProj (your mock) as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

I change the contructor to

```
public DocuSign(DocuSignProperties docuSignProperties) {
    this.initialize(docuSignProperties);
}

public DocuSign(ProjetoDTO projeto, DocuSignProperties docuSignProperties)  {
    this.projeto = projeto;
    this.initialize(docuSignProperties);
}

private void initialize(DocuSignProperties docuSignProperties) {...}
```

and on my test class:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws IOException {
   docuSignProperties = new DocuSignProperties();
   docuSignProperties.setBaseUrl("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
   docuSignProperties.setBasePath("/restapi");

@Test
public void criarDocumento() throws Exception {
    DocuSign docuSign = new DocuSign (projeto1, docuSignProperties);
    docuSign.sendDoc();
    assertNotNull(docuSign);
}
```